# Limit the entries element API will return based on the post date

Tags: php, plugin-elementapi

I'm looking to only return entries that were published in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the criteria for the endpoint, set

```
'postDate' => '>=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-90 days"))
```

Of course you can adjust the date to suit your needs.